# Is it possible to produce and consume a Kafka message in the current HTTP request?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Laravel application with multiple microservices. Microservice `Order` needs to fetch the user information from microservice `User`. To do so, I need to produce a message on a topic, and the microservice `User` consumes the message, generates the required information, and then produces it on the appropriate topic. Then `Order` will in turn should consume the generated information. However, all these things must happen inside the current HTTP request. It must appear as if an API is being invoked and the HTTP request waits until the API call is done.

But as far as I know, Kafka operates as a separate process in the underlying operating system that handles message receiving and sending. I am unaware of how to utilize this capability in the current HTTP request. What I need is the code to wait until the Kafka message is consumed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can produce, yes, but you shouldn't wait for a consumer. Your HTTP server could eventually issue a timeout under several conditions caused by Kafka server, consumer, or external network factors.

You can block the producer flush / ack, and return `201 Accepted` (or 4xx/5xx error) immediately. Then, you should have some external consumer process or thread already running and updating some state (commonly, a database). Then define a separate HTTP endpoint for clients to poll (which would return 404 until the consumer actually wrote some state you're querying).

This follows the [CQRS design pattern and is eventually consistent](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/cqrs.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the mentioned scenario in the question, what if I need the `userId` fetched from `User` microservice for further process of the function? in a function in `Order` microservice I need that `userId` to complete the function.

Comment: As mentioned, store the data in a place it can be joined, such as a database. You'd have some `user-events` topic that the consumer would update the `users` table. Then when a user places an order, with data in `order-events` topic, then that would require a user-id in the payload, so you just query the table to get user information... You dont need to consume the entire `user-events` topic to get details of one user account... Within the context of Kafka, you could use ksqlDB for that - https://developer.confluent.io/courses/ksqldb/lookups-and-joins/